# Which site is best for a question involving Windows8/7/XP spooler and the Zebra ZT230 printer?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I've been a long-time SO participant. But which stack is best for a question involving Windows8/7/XP spooler and the Zebra ZT230 printer? Any suggestions?

Comment: You already have an account on Super User, why do you not think it would fit there?

Comment: Hadn't considered it, but I'll give it a shot. Can't hurt. I think the answer is going to involve knowledge of why IP reset packets are being sent from the spooler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @random noted, [Super User](https://superuser.com/) is a good choice. From the help center:

> Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users. If you have a
>   question about …
>
> - computer hardware,
> - computer software, or
> - personal and home computer networking